# Is there a JSCover SBT plugin for Play to get javascript coverage of my functional tests?

Tags: javascript, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2, fluentlenium

I'm using Play Framework 2.2.x and am having trouble getting JavaScript code coverage of my functional tests with [Fluentlenium](https://github.com/FluentLenium/FluentLenium). I need an sbt plugin for Play that enables getting JavaScript code coverage for functional tests (Selenium,Fluentlenium...)

I was told to use JSCover, but that is a very loosely-coupled solution that will require a lot of time to integrate into my current project.

Is there a plugin that uses the JSCover library that'd be compatible with Play 2.2.x?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

Try looking at the jscover-sbt-plugin:

https://github.com/g00dnatur3/jscover-sbt-plugin

It was developed using Play Framework 2.2.1 and should work for all 2.2.x versions.

Cheers!